# How to upload job artifacts stored in multiple paths in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I would like to specify 2 different paths in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file within the stage `build`. The use case is to upload log files if there were errors during the build otherwise upload different files. Below is the section of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
stages:
  - build

.build_sample:
  stage: build
  image: <sample_image>
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/deploy/images/test
    expire_in: 24 hour

build_test-file:
  extends: .build_sample
  script:
    - execute_script
  allow_failure: true
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    # specify different path if the job fails, otherwise find the files in the "paths" defined in .build_sample section 
    paths:
      - /path/to/log/files
    name: "test-artifact-logs"
```

Can anyone please let me know if this is possible in `gitlab-ci`?

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the artifact paths conditionally.

So you can either:

1. Upload both paths always
2. Move the files you want to a set directory in your script

```yaml
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - path/to/log/files
      - path/to/dist
```

or

```yaml
  script:
    - mkdir ./my-artifacts
    # see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22726
    - |
      if execute_script ; then
          mv path/to/dist ./my-artifacts/
          exit 0
      else
          mv path/to/log/files ./my-artifacts/
          exit 1
      fi
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - my-artifacts
```

Keep in mind you can only specify artifact paths within the workspace. You can't artifact files in other locations (e.g., `- /var/logs/foo` won't work.)