# GitLab CI/CD Artifacts Path all files in folder but one separately

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've got a directory with multiple files:

```
- file1.json
- file2.txt
- file3.json
```

and I'm running a command that creates an `output.txt` in the same folder.

And I want to create two artifacts, one with a zip with the files and another one with the `output.txt`. If I do something like this:

```
  artifacts:
     paths:
     - ${DOWNLOADS_DIR}/*
     - ${DOWNLOADS_DIR}/output.txt
```

Would it work? thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend checking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75714568/how-to-upload-job-artifacts-stored-in-multiple-paths-in-gitlab-ci).

Then, I would suggest trying this:

```
  before_script:
    - DOWNLOADS_DIR="my_artifact/path/to/DOWNLOADS_DIR"
    - mkdir -p $DOWNLOADS_DIR
  script:
    - zip $DOWNLOADS_DIR/output.zip file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
    - cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt >> $DOWNLOADS_DIR/output.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - my_artifact
```

[View all job artifacts in a project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#view-all-job-artifacts-in-a-project)

> You can view all artifacts stored in a project from the **Build** **>**
> **Artifacts** page.

[image]

The full script I used:

```
stages:
   - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install zip
    - DOWNLOADS_DIR="my_artifact/path/to/DOWNLOADS_DIR"
    - mkdir -p $DOWNLOADS_DIR
  script:
    - zip $DOWNLOADS_DIR/output.zip file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
    - cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt >> $DOWNLOADS_DIR/output.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - my_artifact
```

The artifacts I got:
[image]